# Аннотация типов в Python

Tags: python

Как аннотировать аргумент со значением по умолчанию?

```
def bar(a = 33) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: Андрей, пожалуйста, на будущее, задавайте вопросы на хорошем русском языке. Это не "аннотировать аргумент по умолчанию", а "аннотировать аргумент со значением по умолчанию". Это совершенно разные вещи! Исправил в тексте.

Answer (score 2):

Сперва аннотация типа, потом значение по умолчанию:

```
def bar( z : int =12 )->None :
    pass
```

Comment: +1. Я вообще не мог понять, что это за "аннотация по умолчанию"?! (типа Python сам догадается о типе переменной, aka в некоторых ЯП, если переменная от `i` до `n`  -  то `int` и т.д.) А это не аннотация "аргумента по умолчанию", а аннотация аргумента со значением по умолчанию!